# What is the Node.js equivalent to a controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, node.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I have experience programming in ASP.NET MVC. I am learning how to use Node.js, but I am a little confused on what a controller would look like in Node.js.

What would the below code look like in Node.js?

```
[HttpGet]
public Json GetMyResults(){
    //query to database 
}

[HttpPost]
public Json SubmitResults(){
    //query to database 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In NodeJS the abstraction for the controller is defined by the Framework you choose to use.

For example, in Express your controller is just a plain function with two or three arguments.

```
app.get('/users/find', function(req, res) {

  //    
  // The 'req' object contains the request input information
  //
  // This will access the id in query param
  // Ex: /users/find?id=12345
  //
  var userId = req.query.id;

  // Then you'll find it in your database
  Users.findOne({id: userId}).then(function(user) {

     // The 'res' object holds the methods for serving responses
     //
     // Serve a JSON as response with user information
     res.json(user);

  })

});
```

A lot of popular frameworks are express-based or inspired, so this will be a common structure in other projects such [SailsJS](http://sailsjs.org).
For more information on Express checkout the [official website](http://expressjs.com).

Comment: Thank you! This make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

An issue you will run into is that ASP.NET is a platform with a great deal "baked in". Node is an environment which is much more flexible. A common web server library is Express. See an Express tutorial for the answers to your question.

I have generally found the [Scotch IO tutorials](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters) to be quite helpful

Comment: Thanks for the link! Very helpful.